# Alternatives of rubber sealant cement for finalizing patch-plug repair on car tyre?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, car, wheels

I am doing a **patch-plug repair** for a 2mm puncture injury on my car tire:
[image]

I have two questions:

1.) The minimum I got at local stores (in India) is a 6mm patch-plug. Do I need to drill/cut the injury to 6mm diameter using a carbide cutter or should it be **less than 6mm to promote tight fitting** of the plug-patch repair?

2.) I cannot find a **rubber sealant cement** online or at a local store nearby, which is used in the last step to seal the buffed/exposed rubber after installing the patch-plug repair. So, can I use something else like a very thin layer of **high-temperature RTV gasket maker sealant** or **polymer-modified black bitumen paint**, etc. instead? I also have a TPMS sensor installed, but I'm not sure if this RTV sealant will shred/crack into pieces in the future and clog the pressure sensor in the TPMS.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, you need the correct rubber cement as that bonds into both surfaces for an effective seal.

Any other glue or your suggested gasket sealer will fail and could even damage the tire material leading to a more serious failure.

Comment: thanks, so the silicone in the RTV will damage the nylon on the tire? but RTV is nothing but rubber right?

Comment: @Akay you need the stuff that comes with the plug

Comment: @TigerGuy, actually I got only a vulcanization solution with the kit which is applied before the installation, I didn't got rubber cement which is usually applied at the end